# How to skip redirection to https for some http request? How to configure this in jboss web subsystem?

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

I have a requirement in my application where all http request are redirected to https but there is some code in my java servlet where we create http request through code and send it to jobss server where it is translating to https request. But as my servlet do not have capability to handle https response and I do not want to change the servlet code. Is there any way to configure in jboss web system to skip redirection of this http request to https request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add security constraint like this in **web.xml** to disable https for few pages

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>pageswithouthttps</web-resource-name>
    <description>No Description</description>
    <url-pattern>/nohttps/*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <description>No Description</description>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>httpspages</web-resource-name>
    <description>No Description</description>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <description>No Description</description>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to make changes in standalone.xml and do not want to touch the deployed ear. This solution provided me workaround. Thank you for your quick reply.